# Camel JDBC Route - CamelJdbcRowCount missing

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-camel

I have a very simple route to read some rows from a database:

```
  from("timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1&delay=1000").
            setBody(constant("select * from some_table"))
            .to("jdbc:dataSource?outputType=StreamList")
            .log("Processing $simple{in.header.CamelJdbcRowCount} rows")
            .split(body()).streaming().to("direct:createChunk");
```

I want to do some cleanup work after all rows/chunks are processed, and wanted to compare the number of processed rows with the CamelJdbcRowCount from the select to accomplish this.

However, the CamelJdbcRowCount is not set at all. The only JDBC Header I can find is the CamelJdbcColumnNames.

What am I missing?

Is there another/better way to achieve what I want instead of looking at the row count?

**EDIT**: I just noticed that if I remove the 'outputType=StreamList' I get the CamelJdbcRowCount value as expected. I guess this has something to do with that when using a StreamList I get a resultset and a cursor/iterator, so you can't really count the number of rows. It would be nice if the documentation reflected this.

How do I know when all rows are processed?

Comment: What Camel version do you use? Could be a bug fixed in latest release. So try to upgrade.

Comment: Oh I think a StreamList is on-demand so there is no way to know the total count in advance

Answer (score 0):

you have to omit the part `?outputType=StreamList` in your `to`-clause. The log statement itself can also be simplified:

```
.log("read ${header.CamelJdbcRowCount} rows")
```